# Desktop build for ROS2, Gazebo development

Tags: gazebo, ros2

I'm building a desktop PC for ROS2 development and we will make extensive use of Gazebo as well.
What are the guidelines to build a solid PC?
My main questions are:

- CPU. Should we favor number cores or single core performance?
- GPU: I assume nvidia is way to go due to openCL leveraging cuda, but what platform is best? RTX or quadro?

Thank you

Comment: This is a very open-ended question, as the answer depends on "what you are doing with it". Your requirements for hardware will change drastically if you are running reinforcement-based autonomous driving algorithms on Gazebo, than if you are just publishing data and reading from sensors. 

You might want to edit your question to a more specific question. You can take a look at the types of questions not to ask [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)